# Error while predicting a single value using a linear regression model

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, anaconda, sklearn-pandas

I'm a beginner and making a linear regression model, when I make predictions on the basis of test sets, it works fine. But when I try to predict something for a specific value. It gives an error. The tutorial I'm watching, they don't have any errors.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

# Fitting Linear Regression to the dataset
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X, y)

# Visualising the Linear Regression results
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X, lin_reg.predict(X), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (Linear Regression)')
plt.xlabel('Position level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()

# Predicting a new result with Linear Regression
lin_reg.predict(6.5)
```

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=6.5.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: @umopapisdn yes, it said, "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.predict), the input array should have shape `(n_samples, n_features)`. As such, if you want a single example with a single value, you should expect the shape of your input to be `(1,1)`.

This can be done by doing:

```
import numpy as np
test_X = np.array(6.5).reshape(-1, 1)
lin_reg.predict(test_X)
```

You can check the shape by doing:

```
test_X.shape
```

The reason for this is because the input can have many samples (i.e. you want to predict for multiple data points at once), or/and each sample can have many features.

Note: [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html) is a Python library to support large arrays and matrices. [When scikit-learn is installed, Numpy should be installed as well](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html).

Comment: Does this help? What other reference do you need?